# formatting a prepared statement to inquire a database

Tags: java, database, prepared-statement, resultset

I am working on a project to create a login page. To do this I am using a database to store the user information. As of right now there are four columns in my database: username, password, email, and admin.

Right now I am having a problem accessing that database using a prepared statement/Result set format. Right now I get to the third return, print out the imputed username and password then generate an error. Am I formatting my prepared statement incorrectly?

Okay, based of previous answers I have corrected most of my code(thank you) and now I have this error when I am trying to print out of the result set:

java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 2 > 1.

any ideas?

My code:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", "root");
    props.setProperty("password", "root");
    props.setProperty("databaseName", "dbname");

    String ret = ERROR;
    Connection myCon = null;
    try{
        System.out.println("got here 1!");
        Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        System.out.println("got here 2!");
        myCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ipaddresshere:3306/dbname",props);

        System.out.println("got here 3!");
        System.out.println(username);
        System.out.println(password);
        String dbQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM loginTestTable where username = "+username+" AND password = "+password+"";

        //PreparedStatement prep = myCon.prepareStatement(dbQuery);" 
        PreparedStatement ps = myCon.prepareStatement(dbQuery);

        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setString(2, password);

        ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("got here 4!");

        while (result.next()) {
            System.out.println("got here 5!");
            ret = SUCCESS;
            System.out.println("username: "+result.getString(1)+" password: "+result.getString(2)+" email: "+result.getString(3));
            if(result.getString(4).toLowerCase()=="YES"){
                ret = "admin";
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("arg there be an error me matey!");
        ret = ERROR; 
    }finally{
        if(myCon!=null){
            try{
                myCon.close();
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code:

First, you're missing quotes around *username* and *password*.

```
String dbQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM loginTestTable " +
                 "where username = '"+username+"' AND password = '"+password+"'";
```

Second, the `PreparedStatement#setString()` methods have no effect unless you define your query with place holders `?` like

```
String dbQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM loginTestTable " +
                 "where username = ? AND password = ?";
```

Third, you must never compare strings with equality `==` operator. Use `String.equals()` as

```
// also note you need toUpperCase() here
"YES".equals(result.getString(4).toUpperCase());
```

Comment: very helpful but when I get to <br/> <pre>   System.out.println( "username: "+result.getString(1)+" password: "+result.getString(2)); <code>   I still throw an error

Comment: @Missmuffut, that's because you've selected `Count(*)` instead of table columns. Switch to `SELECT * FROM ...` to fetch all the values.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
String dbQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM loginTestTable where username = "+username+" AND password = "+password+"";
```

By:

```
String dbQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM loginTestTable where username = ? AND password = ?";
```